# jquery iframe load dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I am using following jquery script to load another url after successful ajax request.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $loaded = $("#siteloader").data('loaded');
    if($loaded == false){
        $("#siteloader").load(function (){
            if(ad_id != undefined){ 
                var req_url = base_url+'ajax/saveclick/'+ad_id+'/';
                var preloader = $('#preloader');
                var reqloader = $('#reqloader');

                $.ajax({
                    url: req_url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $(preloader).show();
                        $('#adloading').remove();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $(preloader).hide();
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $(reqloader).html(result);
                        $("#siteloader").data("loaded", "true");
                        $("#siteloader").attr("src", base_url+'userpanel/cpa/'+ad_id+'/');
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                $('#reqloader').html('<span class="text-danger">Invalid Approach!</span>');
            }

        });
    }
});

<iframe src="remote_url" id="siteloader"></iframe>
```

I don't want to run ajax again after changing src on iframe and i have also tried to stop it by `$("#siteloader").data("loaded", "true");`

Please suggest me a good solution for this.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to execute the "load" handler once
Simply add the line

```
$("#siteloader").unbind('load');
```

In the **success** callback.

If you want the "load" handler to be executed on each src change, you may do something like that :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#siteloader").load(function () {
            // Move the test in the event Handler ...
            var $loaded = $("#siteloader").data('loaded');
            if ($loaded == false) {
                if (ad_id != undefined) {
                    var req_url = base_url + 'ajax/saveclick/' + ad_id + '/';
                    var preloader = $('#preloader');
                    var reqloader = $('#reqloader');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: req_url,
                        type: 'GET',
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $(preloader).show();
                            $('#adloading').remove();
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $(preloader).hide();
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $(reqloader).html(result);
                            $("#siteloader").data("loaded", "true");
                            $("#siteloader").attr("src", base_url + 'userpanel/cpa/' + ad_id + '/');
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#reqloader').html('<span class="text-danger">Invalid Approach!</span>');
                }

            }
        });
    });
```

Maybe your ad_id variable is not well defined / changed ...

Comment: @seoppc please mark the question solved if it works now